# Edit the Info.plist after eclipse product build

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, info.plist

I have a feature based product which is built using Eclipse. My problem is that I have integrated the "self-update" feature on the rcp application, and after an update, the application bundle is rewrited (I mean the .app bundle, including the Info.plist). I have to edit the Info.plist, because I have some important keys (like the LSBackgroundOnly which is critical, and the "-vm" eclipse argument, in case clients don't have the JRE installed on their computers). So, after an update, all my modifications are removed, and I would like to keep them.

My questions are:

- is it possible to provide a custom Info.plist to be automatically packaged in the bundle by Eclipse? If so, how can I do it?
- If not, can I add some properties which will be automatically added to the Default Info.plist by eclipse? If so, how?

Thanks for your help.

Narutim8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found a solution, so simple I didn't even think about...

The trick is to find in the code the right place where the update is launched by the application, and to copy the **Info.plist** in another place (or to make a **temporary file**).

We also have to find the method called just after the update (right before the **application restart** in our case), and there, move back the **Info.plist** (or write the file from the temporary one). I've just tested it, and it works like a charm ;)

PS: the Info.plist is edited by a script launched after the application installation, provided by a **.pkg**.

Hoping this will help,

narutim8

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no easy way to provide a custom Info.plist file for Eclipse RCP products - see the [Eclipse Bugzilla 339526](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339526) with the feature request.

If you build with [Maven Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/), you can update the Info.plist after `materialize-product` and before `archive-product`. For the self-update, you also need to update the Info.plist inside the repository.

I have written this small [fix-info-plist-maven-plugin](https://github.com/buchen/fix-info-plist-maven-plugin) to do this in my own Tycho product build.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Actually, I only used Maven for a short time (a  months internship) and i haven't done any Java since that time. I upvoted, maybe someone will find your answer useful :)